# AES 256 encryption in C++ and Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, aes

I have a Java code for encryption in place as follows!

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws 
   Exception {  
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw,  "AES");  
    Cipher cipher = null;

    if(isIVUsedForCrypto) {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV));  
    }
    else 
    {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);  
    }
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);  
    return encrypted;  
}  

 public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) { 

    int len = hexString.length()/2;  
    byte[] result = new byte[len];  
    try{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2),16).byteValue();  
    }
    }catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return result;  
}  

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {  
    if (buf == null)  
        return "";  
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);  
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {  
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);  
    }  
    return result.toString();  
}  
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";  
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {  
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));  
}
```

From Java main method:

```
  byte[] result = encrypt(toByte(rawKey), plaintext.getBytes());
```

I need to write the C++ equivalent for the above methods (in java). I am not aware of the C++ classes for Cryptography and would like someone to please provide an example showing the same.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My raw key would be in hexadecimal like -> 729308A8E815F6A46EB3A8AE6D5463CA7B64A0E2E11BC26A68106FC7697E727E

and my final encrypted password is --> 812DCE870D82E93DB62CDA66AAF37FB2

This works in Java but I need a similar solution for C++

Comment: "I am not aware of the C++ classes for Cryptography" .. judging from the comment left below, you *are* aware of at least one library. Have you investigated why it seemingly doesn't do what you're looking for? What other libraries have you tried? Is there some reason it has to be C++ and couldn't instead simple be an OpenSSL api-stack? Or a get-the-job-done thin wrap?

Comment: I have tried Botan but that doesnt give me an hexadecimal encrypted string as output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <crypto++/aes.h>
#include <crypto++/modes.h>
#include <crypto++/filters.h>
#include <crypto++/hex.h>
#include <crypto++/sha.h>
#include <crypto++/md5.h>

QString Foo::decrypt(const QString &password)
{
    string plain;
    string encrypted = password.toStdString();
    // Hex decode symmetric key:
    HexDecoder decoder;
    decoder.Put( (byte *)PRIVATE_KEY,32*2 );
    decoder.MessageEnd();
    word64 size = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
    char *decodedKey = new char[size];
    decoder.Get((byte *)decodedKey, size);
    // Generate Cipher, Key, and CBC
    byte key[ AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    StringSource( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(decodedKey), true,
                  new HashFilter(*(new SHA256), new ArraySink(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH)) );
    memset( iv, 0x00, AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    try {
        CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption Decryptor
        ( key, sizeof(key), iv );
        StringSource( encrypted, true,
                      new HexDecoder(new StreamTransformationFilter( Decryptor,
                                     new StringSink( plain ) ) ) );
    }
    catch (Exception &e) { // ...
    }
    catch (...) { // ...
    }
    return QString::fromStdString(plain);
}

QString Foo::encrypt(const QString &password)
{
    string plain = password.toStdString();
    string ciphertext;
    // Hex decode symmetric key:
    HexDecoder decoder;
    decoder.Put( (byte *)PRIVATE_KEY, 32*2 );
    decoder.MessageEnd();
    word64 size = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
    char *decodedKey = new char[size];
    decoder.Get((byte *)decodedKey, size);
    // Generate Cipher, Key, and CBC
    byte key[ AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    StringSource( reinterpret_cast<const char *>(decodedKey), true,
                  new HashFilter(*(new SHA256), new ArraySink(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH)) );
    memset( iv, 0x00, AES::BLOCKSIZE );
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption Encryptor( key, sizeof(key), iv );
    StringSource( plain, true, new StreamTransformationFilter( Encryptor,
                  new HexEncoder(new StringSink( ciphertext ) ) ) );
    return QString::fromStdString(ciphertext);
}
```

**Update:**

Use above code as follows:

```
//...
#define PRIVATE_KEY "729308A8E815F6A46EB3A8AE6D5463CA7B64A0E2E11BC26A68106FC7697E727E37011"
QString encrypted = Foo::encryptPassword("test");
// use encrypted
```

Personally I don't like to reveal private key in source code. So I'll pass it to compiler in command line:

```
g++ -DPRIVATE_KEY \"\"\"123...\"\"\" ...
```

Where PRIVATE_KEY is your private key in plain text. If you have the key in HEX encode, just remove `Hex decode symmetric key` step.

Comment: yes will try and let u know now...thanks for the example

Comment: does the above code use any library? or can I use it with Botan?

Comment: Ok fine. At present I need to encrypt only using AES-256 algorithm. will it work if I give a raw key as hexadecimal? Is there any line of code i need to remove from encrypt method. Check the edit in question

Comment: If you are planning to give the key as HEX-encoded string, remove lines between two comments (`Hex decode symmetric key` and next comment)

Comment: ok fine I got it and is it for AES 256 ? I do not want to use any salt

Comment: This algorithm uses `AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH` as key length which is 32 bytes in length in my compile of the library. So yes, it's AES-256

Comment: except QString rest other code is pure C++ right? I mean QString belongs to Qt only. Is there any difference between QString and string

Comment: QString belongs to Qt, rest of code is plain C++ plus some convertion between `std::string` and `QString`. `QString` is basically an extended cross-platform string class implementation.

Comment: @ParthDoshi Depends on your system. In my Ubuntu they're `in /usr/include/crypto++`

Comment: My password is let's suppose "test" and key is something like "729308A8E815F6A46EB3A8AE6D5463CA7B64A0E2E11BC26A68106FC7697E727E37011" then How do i write it in c++ . I am not understanding since i m new to C++

Comment: yes i saw it..i am trying it..will inform you whether it is working or not

Comment: hi sorush-r. your code isnt working. the result from C++ and java do not match. Please can u add me on gmail. my gmail id is androidparth@gmail.com. Can u please send me a test message

Comment: I've tested this code and our company is using this for about 3 years. I'm pretty sure this is working well. Maybe there is something wrong in your Java code?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965102/aes-256-encryption-qt-equivalent-for-java      ..It clearly states my problem

Comment: OMG! @sorush-r your code seems to be complex unnecessarily and not readable.

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi Well, it's an old source code, but I am still open for all suggestions (:

https://github.com/soroush/qtz-security/blob/dev/src/crypto.cpp#L50

Comment: I created a Foo class. And I created a static encrypt() function in this class. And if I use the code proposed here as is in my encrypt() function, I get a message saying "Unknow type name '**HexDecoder**'. And QT suggests I use "**CryptoPP::HexDecoder**" instead. But why...? Because I didn't add **Crypto++ library** in my project...? I need to create a library from sources and add it to my project..?