# Undefined reference to CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate when linking

Tags: c++, mingw, crypto++

I am getting the below errors compiling the cryptopp project in Windows.

```
C:\Users\Sajith\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxq8O8x.o:aescbc.cpp:(.text$_ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEjPKv[
__ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEjPKv]+0x2e): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsig
ned int)'
C:\Users\Sajith\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxq8O8x.o:aescbc.cpp:(.text$_ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPv
j[__ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE10deallocateEPvj]+0x28): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate
(void*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is my compilation command :

```
mingw32-g++.exe -o .\aestest2.exe .\aescbc.cpp   -I "C:\cryptopp\Include" -L "C:\cryptopp\Lib" -lcryptopp
```

My libcryptopp.a is located at `C:\cryptopp\Lib`
I tried to find out where `AlignedDeallocate` is declared but I couldn't.

The part of the program that threw this error is below :

```
try
    {
        cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;

        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes
        //  padding as required.
        StringSource s(plain, true, 
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter
        ); // StringSource

#if 0
        StreamTransformationFilter filter(e);
        filter.Put((const byte*)plain.data(), plain.size());
        filter.MessageEnd();

        const size_t ret = filter.MaxRetrievable();
        cipher.resize(ret);
        filter.Get((byte*)cipher.data(), cipher.size());
#endif
    }
    catch(const CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

Suggestions appreciated !

Comment: For what its worth, the sample above should work. The code looks good, and the command to compile it looks well formed.

Answer (score 5):

`AlignedAllocate` is in `misc.h`:

```
$ grep -I AlignedAllocate *
misc.cpp:void * AlignedAllocate(size_t size)
misc.h:CRYPTOPP_DLL void * CRYPTOPP_API AlignedAllocate(size_t size);
secblock.h:                     return (pointer)AlignedAllocate(n*sizeof(T));
```

And:

```
$ grep -R AlignedDeallocate *
misc.cpp:void AlignedDeallocate(void *p)
misc.h:CRYPTOPP_DLL void CRYPTOPP_API AlignedDeallocate(void *p);
secblock.h:                     return AlignedDeallocate(p);
```

However, they are guarded with:

```
#if CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED
CRYPTOPP_DLL void * CRYPTOPP_API AlignedAllocate(size_t size);
CRYPTOPP_DLL void CRYPTOPP_API AlignedDeallocate(void *p);
#endif
```

`CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED` is set in `config.h`:

```
#if CRYPTOPP_BOOL_SSE2_INTRINSICS_AVAILABLE || CRYPTOPP_BOOL_SSE2_ASM_AVAILABLE || defined(CRYPTOPP_X64_MASM_AVAILABLE)
    #define CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED 1
#else
    #define CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED 0
#endif
```

---

You might consider adding the following to `config.h` after Crypto++ makes its choice internally:

```
#undef CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED
#define CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED 1
```

Then, rebuild the library and your program.

---

Something else that may be happening is: MinGW is building the library on a machine with MMX/SSE/SSE2 disabled. Or perhaps they are using `g++ -mno-sse -mno-sse2 ...`.

Then, you come a long with a shiny new Intel or AMD, and based on what g++ enables and the defines in `config.h`, your program expects `AlignedAllocate` and `AlignedDeallocate` because your configuration includes MMX/SSE/SSE2...

This situations is discussed at [config.h | Recommendations](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Config.h#5.6.3_Recommendations) on the Crypto++ wiki. Its why we tell distros to enable and disable things in `config.h`, rather than from the command line. Modifying `config.h` ensures the distro and user programs mostly use the same settings.

If this is the case, then you might try:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -mno-sse -mno-sse2"
mingw32-g++.exe $CXXFLAGS -o .\aestest2.exe .\aescbc.cpp \
  -I "C:\cryptopp\Include" -L "C:\cryptopp\Lib" -lcryptopp
```

There's a slew of defines that cascade based on MMX/SSE/SSE2; see [config.h | Assembly Defines](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Config.h#Assembly_Defines) on the wiki. Because MMX/SSE/SSE2 is disabled, you will get a software-only implementation of AES. It won't perform as well as it could.

Comment: Just for curiosity I have already printed the value of `CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED` before posting this question and it shows 1.

Comment: @sjsam - its defined in `misc.cpp`; see the grep above.

Comment: @sjsam - can you verify the symbol is exported from the library? There could be a bad interaction between `CRYPTOPP_DLL` (effectively, the way to mark things exported), Windows and the Linux on Windows tools.

Comment: Thankyou Jeff, I will check this one out. :-)

Comment: @sjsam - How did you make out? I can set up a test environment and test it with you, if needed.

Comment: Nice of you Jeff !! Compiling CryptoPP with mingw gave me nothing but grief. As i am nearing the deadline I made a decision to switch my design platform from CodeBlocks to VisualStudio as I had issues with other libraries like mysql as well . I recompiled the CryptoPP with VisualStudio and it works like a charm. I was not able to narrow down the issue but I strongly believe that the problem is what you pointed out. When I get back to mingw I will get back to you. :)

Comment: @sjsam - ***if*** you are building the library under CodeBlocks, then I think you need to define `CRYPTOPP_EXPORTS`. When you consume the library, you omit/don't use `CRYPTOPP_EXPORTS`. ***Compiling Crypto++ with mingw gave me nothing but grief....*** - yeah, I avoid Cygwin, MinGW and WINE like the plague. I use the native platform's tools (when in Rome, do as the Romans do...).

Comment: @jww: I have same problem on Linux. And in my case, it is secblock.h that produces 'undefined reference...' error. I tried undefining and defining CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED solution but no success. How to do it now? I use Qt 5 and Fedora 32 bit.

Comment: @jww: It builds successfully defining CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED = 0 for Linux. But problem now arises at runtime. The program crashes stating:  void CryptoPP::memcpy_s(void*, size_t, const void*, size_t): Assertion `dest != __null' failed. For encryption I used sorush-r's code, here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885140/aes-256-encryption-in-c-and-qt-5). Any suggestions please.

Comment: @Jatin - I added additional information about potential MinGW causes. In the end, you should probably avoid MinGW since it appears to be abandoned. I'm pretty sure its no longer being maintained because I filed some bugs against it that were neither acknowledged or fixed. I took MinGW out of my testing rotation because it was more frustrating than fruitful. Try Cygwin or use native Windows tools, like Visual Studio, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I've been experiencing the same thing with MSYS2's version of MinGW64</del>

<del>The solution was to add `-static` before `-lcryptopp`. Hope this works for you!</del>

**Edit**: nevermind my first answer, actually. MSYS2 might have a corrupted version of a shared lib in their repos, but I guess you compiled it yourself.

I'll instead provide a way how to compile Crypto++ with MinGW. You'll need Qt's qmake to generate a Makefile instead of using the one included.

First, open GNUMakefile and look for `TESTOBJS`, as of 5.6.2 it's `bench.o bench2.o test.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o adhoc.o datatest.o regtest.o fipsalgt.o dlltest.o`. You need to remove .cpps with the same names, so you don't build a bloated lib.

Then open cmd.exe (with `PATH` containing MinGW's /bin and a directory where your qmake.exe is), navigate to the directory containing the sources and use these:

```
erase /f GNUmakefile
qmake -project
```

It'll create a file with the name of the current folder and extension ".pro". Open it with a text editor, change

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = cryptopp562
INCLUDEPATH += .
```

to

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = cryptopp
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += static
LIBS += -lws2_32
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -DNDEBUG
```

Replace every `OutputDebugString` with `OutputDebugStringA` in **fipstest.cpp**.

Now you can type `qmake` to generate a new Makefile and use `mingw32-make`. There'll be a ton of warnings, mostly about unused parameters. Nevertheless, nothing serious enough to cancel compilation. `libcryptopp.a` will be in `./release/`.

The example in the question compiles and works perfectly fine with a library compiled this way, tested with MinGW 4.9.2 bundled with Qt and with a standalone MingGW-w64 5.2.0.

The basic idea is taken from [here](http://www.babaei.net/blog/2013/02/15/how-to-build-cpp-cryptographic-library-cryptopp/#CryptoMinGW), I merely improved it.

Comment: This is in fact unrelated. jww's answer is correct.

Comment: @AlexanderShishenko, well, jww's answer says to define `CRYPTOPP_BOOL_ALIGN16_ENABLED` and the OP replied that he'd already checked that it was defined. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderShishenko, but you're right. Not entirely unrelated, because MSYS2, as of now, does in fact have a corrupted shared version of the library in their repository, but the chance that the OP's using MSYS2 **and** the library from the repository is extremely slim. I've edited the answer to instead explain how to compile Crypto++ with MinGW and avoid linking issues.

Comment: @Zireael - good to see you here. Thanks again for the help with [Issue 46](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/45). I see you mentioned ***Qt*** and ***`qmake.exe`***. You will definitely want to visit [Visual Studio](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio) on the Crypto++ wiki. It provides pre-converted Visual Studio 2010 project files (`vs2010.zip`); and pre-converted Visual Studio 2010 project files using dynamic linking compatible with MFC, Qt, etc (`vs2010-dynamic.zip`).

Comment: *"First, open GNUMakefile... You need to remove .cpps with the same names, so you don't build a bloated lib"* - You can now do a ***`make sources`*** and get a list of files you should build for the library and test program. Its now as easy as copy/paste to get your file list.

Answer (score 0):

if you use of `Crypto++` in your program, so attention :

this solution is for linux and if you doing bellow commands, your problem **100 percentage** will **solved!!!**

if you want to linking your `.so` files and conclusively compiling your program , first you must install all `Crypto++` libraries from Synaptic tool in ubuntu or another distribution (debian base linux).

after that you most add `-lcryptopp` or/and `-lcrypto++` to your `.pro` file in qt creator like this :

```
LIBS += -lcryptopp
LIBS += -lcrypto++
```

i had this problem , but my problem solved...

and my code haven't any mistakes

if you want, test that in window and add two top statements in your qt creator in windows.