# Integrate Crypto++ code to Qt Application In Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, crypto++

I try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885140/aes-256-encryption-in-c-and-qt-5) example code of using AES algorithm.
I am new to qt and linux and try to figure out how should I use this library.

I downloaded the file Crypto++ 5.0 from [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/#download) and unzip it . Now I have direcory in ~/Downloads/crypto with many cpp and header files but I dont know what's next. which file should I compile? how can I integrate this to small Qt project? If I copy the code from the link , the compiler cant find all the include files (which is make sense). so what i need to do to run this small example?

I use Qt 5.4.1, th compiler is g++

Comment: You don't mention your Qt version/compiler/specific task. Here is a tutorial for using Crypto++ with mingw http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28809-Compiling-amp-using-Crypto-with-mingw-version-of-Qt

Comment: @demonplus  I edited the question. I dont know mingw and I see this is a tutorial for windows, I will give a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the blog describing Crypto++, Qt and Linux:

https://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/crypto-and-linux/

The main idea is that you should not using downloaded files but use terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libcrypto++8 libcrypto++8-dbg libcrypto++-dev
```

To add library to the project use the following:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/crypto++ -lcrypto++
INCS += -I/usr/include/crypto++
```

See the first link for more details, hope it helps.